# Tried everything but nothing seems to work - Eclipse not starting -java was started but returned exit code=13 error

Tags: eclipse

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlCIE.png)

error log says - 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

PATH Variable is set to -
C:\Users\Drako\Downloads\libs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe

JAVA_HOME is set to -
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin

Please help!!!

Comment: This works !!! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 32 bit eclipse with 64 bit Java. This won't work. 
Use 64 bit eclipse this problem will not be there

Comment: And if you're going to use the latest release of Java, consider using the latest release of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks this works!!!